# loadPlaylist function doesn't work in Flash mode of the IFrame player API

Tags: youtube-api

**Name of API affected:**

IFrame player API

**Issue summary:**

loadPlaylist() function doesn't work in Flash mode of the IFrame player API.

**Steps to reproduce issue:**

Please Visit the demo page I created for this bug:

http://www.gilgoldshlager.com/youtube_bug.html

**Expected output:**

Be able to load and switch between playlists.

**Actual results:**

Not able to load and switch between playlists.

**Notes:**

I wrote all the reproduce steps in the bug demo page I created:

http://www.gilgoldshlager.com/youtube_bug.html

Please let me know if it is a bug or if I'm doing anything wrong.

Thank you, Gil.

Comment: This sort of thing is best left to the issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3810

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, I wasn't sure where should I post this, that's why I posted this in both places.

Will like to know please if it is a bug or if I just don't load the playlists right.
As this is my first time dealing with playlists and not regular individual videos.